# Why coefficients from logistic regression are not proportional to bad rate?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, data-science-model, statsmodels

I am building a logistic regression model in Python with `statsmodels.api.Logit`. The model contains 12 features that are encoded using `pandas.get_dummies()`.
My final training dataset (`xTrain`) looks like this:

| feature1_A | feature1_B | feature2_B | feature2_C | feature_2_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

feature1 is a categorical feature that contains 3 modalities (or categories) A, B, and C (C is used as a base reference so it does not appear in my training set) and feature2 contains 4 modalities (and A is the base reference).

After the training I print the coefficients in my model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(df_final, df_final["target"], test_size=0.30, random_state=48379)

logit_model = sm.Logit(yTrain.astype(float), sm.add_constant(xTrain.astype(float)))

result = logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
```

But the issue is that my coefficients are not proportional to the bad rate of my modalities:

For `feature2`, the coefficients are positively proportional to the bad rate*

- Modality A has a bad rate of 42% and a model coeff of 0
- Modality B has a bad rate of 52% and a model coeff of 0,19
- Modality C has a bad rate of 57% and a model coeff of 0,28
- Modality D has a bad rate of 60% and a model coeff of 0,55

But for `feature1`, the coefficients do not make sense:

- Modality A has a bad rate of 64% and a model coeff of -0.06
- Modality B has a bad rate of 42% and a model coeff of -0.48
- Modality C has a bad rate of 49% and a model coeff of 0

Here you will noticed that the modality A has a coefficient which is lower than modality C, even though modality A has a higher bad rate. If I'm not mistaken, this means that the model predicts modality A to be less risky than modality C, which does not make sense because the bad rate is actually higher.

Is there a reason I would have such inversion i.e. the model coefficients not being proportional to the bad rate? Are there any ways to fix this?

**bad rate: number of observation with target = 1 (bad) divided by total number of observation*

Comment: I am a little confused on your comments of modality A and C, since both feature 1 and 2 have A and C and one of those are in the intercept and you did not list the intercept amount. But coefficients do not act alone. For example suppose Feature2-D always has Feature1-B active. Then the equation will be intercept + 0.55 - 0.48. Which would be higher compare to Feature2-B with Feature1-C. The coef means all else held the same. But if there is a combination of these categories that always exists, that effects the outcome. How does the model predict? Is it good for your metric and problem?

Comment: @Craig My comment about modality A and C was for feature1 only. In feature2 everything looks normal and proportional to me as bad rate_{modality_B} > bad rate_{modality_A} and coeff_{modality_B} > coeff_{modality_A}. However in feature 2 we've got bad rate_{modality_B} < bad rate_{modality_A} but coeff_{modality_B} > coeff_{modality_A}. It is inversed. I didn't mention the intercept because it is a constant and shouldn't be relevant for my issue. The model predicts well yes, but I realized that the performance is almost the same when I remove the features that cause risk inversion.

Comment: If it predicts well, then it seems to be the combination(interaction) of categories. You can try to plot the interaction. Since these care categoricals one-hot encoded, everything being 0 or 1 makes the plot easier. Can even plot the score for each combination. Another view you can try is to not use an intercept and do not remove a category. Now you will get a representation with a coef for each category combination. But overall, nothing looks strange here from what the little I see but it is worth diving deeper into residuals and plots.

Comment: Thanks for the help Craig, I'll definitely dive into more details.